# Class "Redis" not found after server updates

Tags: laravel, redis

Ok So after doing a sudo apt upgrade on my ubuntu server my Laravel site is down and is saying Class "Redis" not found on every page. I'm using php 8.1 on laravel 9.45

I have tried `sudo apt install php-redis` but it is already installed and I have tested `redis-cli ping` and it returns PONG as expected. I have tried switching the reference in `config/database.php` from `'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis')` to `'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis')` and no difference. I tried `composer install predis/predis` which was already there but it upgraded it to v2.0.3. I have rebooted several times to no avail.

At a total loss. Any suggestions?

*** EDIT ***

I noticed that my database.php value is being overriden in my .env file, changing from phpredis to predis here i get a ```could not find driver

select * from `users` where `id` = 77 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1``` error where 77 is my user id

Comment: How are you running Laravel on this server?  A page with `phpinfo()` may give you details about the PHP setup including installed modules and the configuration files being used.

Comment: So I added a test.php and there is no reference of Redis on this page (it does exist on my dev copy)

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out my server upgrade had removed the mysqli extension and the redis extension. adding these both back resolved my issue.